# Building a numpy maxtix

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to build a translated matrix from a file. The file looks like the following, and represents onset and offset times for piano notes

```
OnsetTime   OffsetTime  MidiPitch
0.500004    0.85356     37
1.20712     1.50441     38
1.80171     2.0517      39
...
```

I am trying to flatten this to a piano state representation and event times like such

```
Event    State
time     Piano state, array of length 88
...
```

To do this I have constructed the follow code

```
eventArray = np.array([])
with open('event_log.txt') as tsv:
        noteState = [0] * 88
        iterator = iter(csv.reader(tsv, dialect="excel-tab"))
        next(iterator)
        for line in iterator:
            notePosition = int(float(line[2])) - 21
            noteState[notePosition] = 1
            np.concatenate(eventArray, np.array([float(line[0]), noteState]))
            noteState[notePosition] = 0
            np.concatenate(eventArray, np.array([float(line[1]), noteState]))
```

But when I execute this I get the following error

```
   File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
   np.concatenate(eventArray, np.array([float(line[0]), noteState]))
   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How should I be building this matrix? I am using numpy to slice and reshape the matrices as needed.

**EDIT**

After trying the suggestions in the comment I now have

```
np.concatenate(eventArray, np.array([[float(line[0])], noteState]))
```

And receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    np.concatenate(eventArray, np.array([[float(line[0])], noteState]))
 TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: That is subtle, but it resulted in a new error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: I think I was wrong with that one I apologize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `concatenate` iteratively.  `np.concatenate` returns a new array each step.  It does not modify an array in place.

```
alist = []
with open('event_log.txt') as tsv:
        noteState = [0] * 88
        iterator = iter(csv.reader(tsv, dialect="excel-tab"))
        next(iterator)
        for line in iterator:
            notePosition = int(float(line[2])) - 21
            noteState[notePosition] = 1
            alist.append(np.array([float(line[0]), noteState]))
            noteState[notePosition] = 0
            alist.append(np.array([float(line[1]), noteState]))
```

That should create a list of arrays.  If those arrays are all the same length, then

```
arr = np.array(alist)
```

should create a 2d array of floats.  If they differ in length, I'd suggest

```
arr = np.concatenate(alist)
```

to make a flat (1d) array of the same values.

I'm assuming the rest of the code is correct.

Print `alist` to verify that the values look reasonable.